# I am using split function in jquery but I am not getting how split string on given condition?

Tags: jquery

I know about split function but here I want to know how it's splitting on a 
  given condition.

```
   var countries_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);

  data= "country,population,area,density,migration,gdp,literacy,phones
       Afghanistan ,31056997,647500,48,23.06,700,36,3.2
       Albania ,3581655,28748,124.6,-4.93,4500,86.5,71.2
       Algeria ,32930091,2381740,13.8,-0.39,6000,70,78.1
       American Samoa ,57794,199,290.4,-20.71,8000,97,259.5
       Andorra ,71201,468,152.1,6.6,19000,100,497.2"
```

Comment: yeah I know, but I don't get an answer yet so that's why I post again

Comment: I want to know how string will split on given condition

Comment: Not getting an answer because you didn't explain what expected results are and what you are getting instead. Both questions are far too vague